# How do I use an if statement inside a for loop to check multiple servers to see if a directory exists/to create a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to get my script to ssh to multiple servers and check to see if a directory needs to be created or already exists.

I noticed the script that I have created runs with no errors but it creates the directory needed on "server1" but then when it reaches "server2" is says (echo)"directory is already created" but the directory is not present in server2.From my understanding after it creates the directory on "server1" it then recognizes that it was created on "server1" so it falls to (echo)"directory is already created".

I want to use a for loop with an if statement to make it run through all the servers specified so It can tell me if each server has that directory or needs that directory to be created.

```
#!/bin/bash


host=(server1 server2)
HOME_PATH=/opt/test

    for my_hosts in "${host[@]}"
    do
        if [ !  -d "$HOME_PATH" ]
        then
        echo "${my_hosts}"
        ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@${my_hosts} 'mkdir -p '${HOME_PATH}''
        echo "${HOME_PATH} was created"
        else
        echo "${my_hosts}"
        echo "'${HOME_PATH}' directory is already created"

        fi
    done
```

Comment: You appear to be checking for the presence of the directory on the source host rather than the remote hosts in the `host` array.  You would need to perform that check on each of the remote hosts.

Comment: `-d "$HOME_PATH"` checks the directory on the local machine, not on the remote one.

Comment: ssh to the server first then check the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You for the help. I figured it out.

```
#!/bin/bash


host=(server1 server2)
HOME_PATH=/opt/test

for my_hosts in "${host[@]}"
do
    
    ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@${my_hosts} "
        if [ !  -d "$HOME_PATH" ]
        then
            echo "${my_hosts}"
            mkdir -p '${HOME_PATH}
            echo "${HOME_PATH} was created"
        else
            echo "${my_hosts}"
            echo "'${HOME_PATH}' directory is already created"

        fi
    "
done
```